# OAuth2 and Microsoft Graph API for my Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, office365

I'd like to add an Office365/Graph Calendar integration to an existing Node.js app (hosted on AWS).  I've already done a similar integration with Google's Calendar, and it was trivial to get set up. I'm not having nearly as much luck with the Microsoft version of things.

I've found at least 4 different ways to register an app (get a clientId and clientSecret), and I seem to get different errors for each of them, but can't get any to work properly.

I think a large part of my problem is that I've never had to work in the MS ecosystem before, so I don't have a lot of the baseline knowledge that the documentation assumes.

I'm not looking to host anything with Microsoft - do I even need an Azure account?

I'd like to allow any user with an Office365 account to connect it to my app - do I need to learn about Active Directory to do this?  Does this part of it require Azure?

I've found instructions for using both https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2 and https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0 for this, do I need to worry about which version I use depending on how I registered my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt, you can do this without an Azure account if you use the `oauth2/v2.0` auth endpoint. When you do that, you can register on apps.dev.microsoft.com using a Microsoft account.

See [this tutorial](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/node) for doing it with the Outlook REST API, which is similar to the Graph (in fact, for Calendar operations the calls and entities are identical).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph leverage Azure AD to authenticate and authorize users. The doc refers as:

> To get your app authorized, you must get the user authenticated first. You do this by redirecting the user to the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) authorization endpoint, along with your app information, to sign in to their Office 365 account. Once the user is signed in, and consents to the permissions requested by your app (if the user has not done so already), your app will receive an authorization code required to acquire an OAuth access token.

So you need to register an Azure account for configure the Azure AD service. Refer https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization for more info.

Meanwhile, to implement Microsoft Graph in node.js application, you can refer the following code sample for your information.

- [Microsoft Graph service app sample using Node.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-App-only#microsoft-graph-service-app-sample-using-nodejs)
- [An Office 365 API sample app using Node, Express and Ejs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Node-Express-Ejs-Sample-App#an-office-365-api-sample-app-using-node-express-and-ejs)
- [Office 365 Node.js Connect sample using Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-Connect#office-365-nodejs-connect-sample-using-microsoft-graph)